# How to query a file geodatabase using GDAL/OGR C# for records with an invalid geometry

Tags: gdal, c#, ogr

Presently, I have a snippet of code that works well when iterating over a file geodatabase. The problem I'm currently having is that, on occasion, a geometry is supplied that is invalid, such as a stacked point at the end of a line segment that, when `GetNextFeature` is called, causes an exception of an "Invalid curve".  After digging into the documentation, it appears that the geometry always returns with the query.  Despite me not including it in the `SELECT` statement and even when I attempt to apply a field filter on the geometry field, the error continues to persist.

Is there a better way to filter these errors?

I attempted to use the "SQLite" dialect with a call of `ST_IsValid` in the `WHERE` clause to only pull the valid items, but that still didn't work.  My assumption there is that they may be "Sqlite Valid", but not GDAL/OGR valid.  Any guidance?

```
using (var fgdbDriver = Ogr.GetDriverByName("OpenFileGDB"))
    using (var ds = fgdbDriver.Open(path, 0))
    {
       var sql = $"SELECT {field} FROM {layerName}";
       var execResult = ds.ExecuteSQL(sql, null, "");
       while ((feature = execResult.GetNextFeature()) != null)
       {
           //do work
       }
    }
```

Comment: Does SQLite dialect work for you generally? What does `select spatialite_version()` return?

Comment: We had never used the dialect previously, but I started to look for ways to filter "really bad" shapes from the select statement, so I attempted to see if that would work but to no avail.  Executing the above query yielded: `4.3.0-RC1`

Comment: That version does already have functions ST_IsValid and ST_MakeValid http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-4.2.0.html.

Comment: Right, but even if I exclude the ones that are false for ST_IsValid, the loop still blows up on the invalid geometries wnen GetNextFeature is called.  My adjusted query was:
`"SELECT {field} FROM {layerName} WHERE ST_IsValid(Shape) = 1"`